# How to mask the content of a text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am looking to mask the content of a text file.

Ex: The text file contains data like

```
Peter|peter@gmail.com|312-445-9988|....|  
John|john@gmail.com|123-457-6789|....|
```

Expected Output:

```
Peter|XXXXX@gmail.com|XXX-XXX-XXXX|....|  
John|XXXX@gmail.com|XXX-XXX-XXXX|....|
```

I have to mask the content like phone number and mail ID till peter not @gmail.com

Here is my code that I tried I have tried till reading the data from the text file after that I am not getting any ideas...

```
public class DataMasking {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Filepath"));
    String str;

    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {

        parts.add(str);
        }
    int size = parts.size();
    //we are reducing the size by one because we are not counting the first line(Only contains file name and time stamp).
    size = size-1;
    System.out.println("The Number of lines in the text file  "+size);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So do you need to mask the data when printing on the screen?

Comment: What are the details of the masking you need to provide? Are you meant to remove the first bit of the email address? Replace it with a * or something like that? How about phone number?

Comment: Mask the data and save the data in some other file. -Nick DeFazio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so may be you want something like this. Try it -

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
String str;

List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        parts.add(str);
    }
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> emailPart=new LinkedList<String>();
List<String> numberPart=new LinkedList<String>();
for(int i=1;i<parts.size();i++){
    String[] strArr=parts.get(i).split("\\|");
    for(int j=0;j<strArr.length;j++){
        if(strArr[j].matches(".*@.*")){
            int index=strArr[j].indexOf("@");
            emailPart.add(strArr[j].substring(0, index).replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]", "X")+
                    strArr[j].substring(index, strArr[j].length()));
        }
        if(strArr[j].matches("[0-9\\-]+")){
            numberPart.add(strArr[j].replaceAll("[0-9]", "X"));
        }
    }
        newList.add(strArr[0]+"|"+emailPart.get(i-1)+"|"+numberPart.get(i-1));
}
System.out.println(newList);
```

Comment: Hi This should be the expected output:                                                        Peter|XXXXX@gmail.com|XXX-XXX-XXXX|....|  
John|XXXX@gmail.com|XXX-XXX-XXXX|....|

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please do check it and let me know if its working for you.